# Issue in getting Next Week value in button click android

Tags: android, date, calendar, week-number, weekday

I want to get next week value in button click so below is my code

**OnCreate Method I declare Calender Object and print Current date**

```
    int WeekNumber;
    Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
    SimpleDateFormat mDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM");
    String printDate = mDF.format(mCalendar.getTime());
    mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 6);
    String printDate2 = mDF.format(mCalendar.getTime());

    System.out.println(printDate + " >> " + printDate2);
    mTextView.setText(printDate + " >> " + printDate2);
```

**Next Button Click**

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            WeekNumber++;
            String ss=getNextWeek(WeekNumber);
            System.out.println("ss "+ss);
            mTextView.setText(ss);
        }
    });
```

**getNextWeek() Method Code**

```
public static String getNextWeek(int weekFromToday) {
    System.out.println("Pass Wee "+weekFromToday);
    Calendar mCalendar =  Calendar.getInstance();
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 
            mCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) + weekFromToday);          

    SimpleDateFormat mDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM");
    String printDate = mDF.format(mCalendar.getTime());
    System.out.println(printDate);

    //gestureEvent.setText(reportDate);
    mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 6);
    String printDate2 = mDF.format(mCalendar.getTime());
    System.out.println(printDate + " >> " + printDate2);
    return printDate + " >> " + printDate2;        
}
```

When I run above code current week dispaly right like `02 Febuarry >> 08 Febuary` but when I click next button it will print wrong week value  like `23 March >> 29 March` so any idea how can I solve it ?

Comment: int weekNumber = what?where do you first set the value of weekNumber

Comment: @user2450263  :See my answer so you will get idea about it!!

Answer (score 2):

I got solution in y code i initialise weekNumber value as

```
WeekNumber=mCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

so i just comment above line and rest of code is as it is and it is working fine for me!!